# How to do addition datagrid view and get it displayed at datagrid view

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to add row 1 and row 2 and get it displayed on row 3 but I am facing some errors can someone please help thanks
[The Error at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xx9vP.jpg)

```
       private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   /// Click button it will do the adding 
    {
        String a;    // total value for row 3 cell 0
        dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value);
        Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[0].Value);
        a = dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value + dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value;               /// error
        dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[0].Value = a;

        String b;// total value for row 3 cell 1
        dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        b = dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[1].Value = b;

        String c;// total value for row 3 cell 2
        dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        c = dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[2].Value = c;
    }
```

Comment: Is the grid databound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are adding two object types this will always throw error because it's not allowed by compiler.

alternatively, you can use:

```
var d = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value) + Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[0].Value);
        dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[0].Value = d;
```

Use this link to understand convert class in c# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert(v=vs.110).aspx